# dynamic axes when using ggplot for shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, axes

I am creating a website using Shiny. The website displays figures of individual data. Some individuals have data between 0-1, outliers have data between 3-4.

I want the y axis on the figures displayed on the website to *always* start at 0 and up to the maximum data value for that subject +0.5. This value will change based on the individual selected. 
Currently I am using:

```
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 3.5))
```

but of course this fixes the y-axes at 0 to 3.5. If I put nothing, the axes are free to vary.

Any way to set the axes based on the data being displayed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To force them in `ggplot` to start at zero:

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA)
```

Comment: You can also do `expand_limits(y=0)`.